# Passing a variable to a function (scope problem)

Tags: javascript, scope

I'm trying to pass the value of *p* to the alert function - unfortunately at the moment it just comes up as *undefined*. I think the problem is because when that function is called *p* doesn't exist anymore. How would I pass *p* to that function and make it retain the value?

```
function B(p,u) {
    var foo = {};
    foo[u] = function(p) {
        alert('visit internal page '+p);
    };
    $.router(foo);
}

B("about", "!/about");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just leave it off the parameter list, like this:

```
function B(p,u) {
    var foo = {};
    foo[u] = function() {
        alert('visit internal page '+p);
    };
    $.router(foo);
}
```

Currently you're specifying a parameter `p` on the inner function, and unless that's provided when it's called (doesn't seem it is) that more local `p` variable will be `undefined`.  Instead just don't specify it as a parameter, and it'll use the `p` from the parent scope.

Comment: Fantastic, that was easier than I expected! No idea why that works though, I'll have to do some research. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @RichW - any variables in the parent scope are available to use, any parameter on a function at *any* level however has to be specified, so when you have `function(p)` and just call it via `foo[u]()`, it'll be `undefined`...since you didn't pass any parameters, but by leaving it off the only `p` it can possibly use is the one in the parent scope...does that make any more sense?

Comment: Makes perfect sense now, thanks Nick! Unfortunately it's one of those problems that seems difficult to research on Google as you don't know what to type in!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have **two** `p` variables at the same time.

```
function B(outer_p, u) { // <- first p
    var foo = {};
    foo[u] = function(inner_p) { // <- second p
        alert('visit internal page '+ outer_p); // depending on what 
    };                                          // you want to display here
    $.router(foo);
}
```

Comment: I was hoping the value of p would inherit through the functions (guess it doesn't work like that!). Thanks for the info!

Comment: What do you mean by inherit? Outer `p` is available in your inner function. **But** if you declare `p` in the inner function parameter list, it will be assigned `undefined` by default and will cover/hide the outer `p` because of name collision.